# Displaying different messages based on data from WeatherAPI in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, openweathermap, weather-api

I've been trying to display different messages when data from the OpenWeatherAPI (Current Weather version) gets passed in. I want a message for the different temperature and a message displayed for the different descriptions displayed at the same time. The problem is that the message isn't updating when the data gets passed. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's the code for the Aside.js file:

```
//Aside Component - used for suggesting things to wear based on the location

//DEPENCENCIES
import React, { useState } from 'react'


function Aside() {
    /* PSUEDOCODE:

    TRYING TO USE THE DATA BEING PULLED IN AND BASED ON THE DATA, THERE'S A DIFFERENT MESSAGE BASED ON THE WEATHER AND THE DESCRIPTION

        dependencies - import WeatherCard and WeatherApp so I can use the values in the WeatherCard & WeatherApp for my algorithm
    
        useState - to set the initial value of the aside. say something like, "type zipcode to get suggestions for attire"

        setMessage - to grab the information on what to say when the zip code is displayed

        ex) const setMessage = async () => {
            use if/else statements to choose which message to display. use emojis!
                an if/else statement for weather[0].description
                an if/else statement for main.temp
                an if/else statement for main.humidity
            nest all of the if/else statements in a trycatch, so if it doesn't work, it sends an error message


        useEffect - use useEffect to run the setMessage function
        ex)
        useEffect(() => {

        
        , []}) <--- This is where I put the zipcode to indicate that it wont run unless the zipcode has a value

        const display - to display the message

        return - returning the const display
    
    */


    let [message, setMessage] = useState("Type in ZipCode to get suggestions for attire!")

    /* COMMENTED OUT TO KEEP THE SITE FROM CRASHING. FINISH CODING THIS LATER
    const { zipCode } = useParams()*/

    setMessage = ({ WeatherData }) => {
        try {
            //MESSAGES FOR TEMPERATURE
            if (WeatherData.main.temp > 100) {
                message = "It's hot.... like really hot... leathers not recommended at all..."
            } else if(WeatherData.main.temp < 70) {
                message = "it's warm today! No need for bundling up"
            } else if(WeatherData.main.temp < 45) {
                message = "It's not that cold outside today, but a small sweater will do"
            } else if(WeatherData.main.temp < 20) {
                message = "Brrr, chilly! try putting on a Jacket!"
            } else {
                message = ""
            }

            //MESSAGES FOR DESCRIPTION - tell the users what to bring/buy
            if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "clear sky") {
                message = "You might want to get some sunglasses"
            } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "shower rain") {
                message = "Make sure you have an umbrella"
            } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "rain" && WeatherData.weather[0].description == "thunderstorm") {
                message = "Grab an umbrella! It's pouring!"
            } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "snow") {
                message = "get your snowboots 'cause its snowin outside."
            } else {
                message =""
            }

        } catch (error) {
            message = "No zipcode, no attire suggestions. sorry..."
        }
    }

    
    /* COMMENTED OUT TO KEEP THE SITE FROM CRASHING. FINISH CODING THIS LATER
    useEffect(() => {
        setMessage()
    }, [zipCode])*/

    return (
        <div className='asideContainer'>
            {message}
        </div>
    )
}




export default Aside
```

And here's the import of it in the App.js file

```
      <Aside zipCode={zipCode} weatherData={weatherData} />
```

I got the initial message in the useState to pull up but I got stuck in trying to update the message. I'm very much of a beginner on using React, so I need some help

Answer (score 0):

You can use one more state for description and set states based on message/description as below-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


function Aside() {
    let [message, setMessage] = useState("Type in ZipCode to get suggestions for attire!")
    let [description, setDescription] = useState("");

    const getWeaterDetails = ({ WeatherData }) => {
      let  weatherMessage = "";
      let weatherDescription = "";
      try {
            if (WeatherData.main.temp > 100) {
                weatherMessage = "It's hot.... like really hot... leathers not recommended at all..."
            } else if(WeatherData.main.temp < 70) {
                weatherMessage = "it's warm today! No need for bundling up"
            } else if(WeatherData.main.temp < 45) {
                weatherMessage = "It's not that cold outside today, but a small sweater will do"
            } else if(WeatherData.main.temp < 20) {
                weatherMessage = "Brrr, chilly! try putting on a Jacket!"
            } else {
                weatherMessage = ""
            }

            if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "clear sky") {
                weatherDescription = "You might want to get some sunglasses"
            } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "shower rain") {
                weatherDescription = "Make sure you have an umbrella"
            } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "rain" && WeatherData.weather[0].description == "thunderstorm") {
                weatherDescription = "Grab an umbrella! It's pouring!"
            } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "snow") {
                weatherDescription = "get your snowboots 'cause its snowin outside."
            } else {
                weatherDescription =""
            }
            setMessage(weatherMessage);
            setDescription(weatherDescription);

        } catch (error) {
            weatherMessage = "No zipcode, no attire suggestions. sorry..."
        }
    };

    setMessage = ({ WeatherData }) => {
        
    }



    return (
        <div className='asideContainer'>
            {message}
            {description}
        </div>
    )
}




export default Aside
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need at all for any local `message` state as it is completely derived from the passed `weatherData` prop. Just compute it directly and render.

Example:

```
<Aside weatherData={weatherData} />
```

```
import React from 'react'l

function Aside({ weatherData }) {
  let message = "Type in ZipCode to get suggestions for attire!";

  // MESSAGES FOR TEMPERATURE
  if (WeatherData.main.temp > 100) {
    message = "It's hot.... like really hot... leather's not recommended at all..."
  } else if (WeatherData.main.temp < 70) {
    message = "It's warm today! No need for bundling up"
  } else if (WeatherData.main.temp < 45) {
    message = "It's not that cold outside today, but a small sweater will do"
  } else if (WeatherData.main.temp < 20) {
    message = "Brrr, chilly! try putting on a Jacket!"
  }

  // MESSAGES FOR DESCRIPTION - tell the users what to bring/buy
  if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "clear sky") {
    message = "You might want to get some sunglasses"
  } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "shower rain") {
    message = "Make sure you have an umbrella"
  } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "rain" && 
      WeatherData.weather[0].description == "thunderstorm"
  ) {
    message = "Grab an umbrella! It's pouring!"
  } else if (WeatherData.weather[0].description == "snow") {
    message = "get your snowboots 'cause it's snowin outside."
  }

  return (
    <div className='asideContainer'>
      {message}
    </div>
  );
}
```